# Rewrite SQLAlchemy query before sending to engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to rewrite the final, compiled raw query bytes before they are sent to the underlying database engine? I've looked at the Events API, but it doesn't seem to expose such low-level events.

Use case: I want to add a string to the beginning of all queries, containing contextual meta data:

```
/* {"trace_id":"1234","client_ip":"1.2.3.4", ...} */ SELECT ...
```

The data is extracted from the database's query logs, and used to correlate events with other services in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `before_cursor_execute` event with `retval=True`, as shown in https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/Profiling

```py
@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_cursor_execute", retval=True)
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement,
    parameters, context, executemany):
  statement = "/* {} */ {}".format(
    json.dumps({
      "trace_id": "1234",
      "client_ip": "1.2.3.4",
    }),
    statement
  )
  return statement, parameters
```